# rust+lapin, how do I exit async_global_executor::block_on() after processing one message or after some wait time duration?

Tags: rust, rabbitmq

I am using lapin to consume messages from RabbitMQ via the async_global_executor::block_on() function.

I would like exit/return from this function after consuming one message or after some wait time period has elapsed irrespective of the count of messages still in the queue.

Does next() method of lapin::Consumer have a timeout argument?

I am using the example code in Crate lapin website as an example.

[lapin AMQP consumer example](https://docs.rs/lapin/latest/lapin/)

Comment: You could use [`timeout`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.15.0/tokio/time/fn.timeout.html) to run `consumer.next()` for no longer than a pre-set period: `if let Ok(Some(delivery)) = timeout(Duration::from_millis(10), consumer.next()).await { ... process the message ... }`